# How can I execute custom SQL commands using ORACLE SQLLDR

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sql-loader

I have SQL statements as follows:

```
INSERT INTO PERSON(PERSON_ID, YEAR_OF_BIRTH) VALUES (1, 0);
UPDATE PERSON SET PERSON_ID=2;
```

How can I execute such type of SQL commands contained successively in a single file? I need to execute this SQL file in the Java code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct an `sql` statement with both the queries (INSERT and UPDATE) using `PreparedStatement` and executes `executeBatch` which is according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) `Submits a batch of commands to the database for execution and if all commands execute successfully, returns an array of update counts`
like

```
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```